# Tell Xcode to launch on iPad only

Tags: xcode, ios

I'm developing an app for the iPad. If i have both my iPhone and iPad plugged in, Xcode prefers that the Active Executable is my iPhone.

Is there any way to tell Xcode to launch the app on my iPad and NOT the iPhone? It keeps switching back to the phone and I have to keep reselecting iPad in the drop down.

Comment: You could just unplug the iPhone...

Comment: I could! But I was tethering and charging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Window > Organizer
2. Right click iPhone under Devices
3. Select "ignore device"